# XHTML and string manipulation and pattern replacement

Tags: vb.net, string, xhtml

I need to process html and I need it to be valid from XHTML perspective. For instance self-closing tags, such as `<br>` and `<hr>` in XHTML should be `<br />` and `<hr />` respectively.

So to take care of this issue, I converted my HTML to text and replace all `<br>` tags with `<br />` and `<hr>` - with `<hr />`.

Now the issue is that some `<hr>` tags have properties. For example:

```
<hr width="100%" size="3" align="center" style="color: rgb(153,153,153);">
```

In his case the replacement becomes more complicated as I cannot simply use

```
str = str.Replace("<hr>","<hr/>")
```

Is there an easier way then writing a function that searches for every occurrence of `"<hr"` and then looks for the following `">"` and replaces it with `"/>"`?

Comment: You'r probably looking for some sort of a [HTML Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421316/what-does-html-parsing-mean).

Comment: You could go for regular expressions, would make it a lot easier to replace the contents :)

Comment: Icepickle, could you help me with regular expressions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)